# How to write the prism as a colimit of simplices (in the category of simplicial sets)?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, limits-colimits

It is intuitively clear that a prism $\Delta ^n\times \Delta ^1$ can be triangulated. If I am interpreting this correctly, it should be possible to give a formula for the prism as a colimit (in the diagram of simplicial sets) of some diagram consisting of copies of $\Delta ^{n+1}$.

Is this possible? What are the formulas?

Comment: The space $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1$ is a solid square, which is a union of two copies of $\Delta^2$, so you should expect $\Delta^n \times \Delta^1$ to be a union of (some number of) copies of $\Delta^{n+1}$. Considering the low-dimensional cases might help you find a formula.

Comment: @CliveNewstead you're right. I edited the question. Thanks! (I tried to work this out but kept messing up. I'll keep trying in the meantime.)

Comment: @CliveNewstead I've just realized it may not have been clear that I'm looking for a colimit in the category of simplicial sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \Delta^n \times \Delta^1$. Let $U$ be the *disjoint* union of the $n+1$ simplices of $X$. The inclusions give a canonical map $U \to X$. This is an epimorphism (why?).

In **sSet** (or any presheaf category, or even topos), epimorphisms are given by equivalence relations: there is a coequalizer diagram

$$ U \times_X U \rightrightarrows U \to X $$

This decomposes into the individual pullbacks. Since all of the inclusions are monic, we can simplify this to a coequalizer diagram

$$ \coprod_{i<j} (s_i \cap s_j)  \rightrightarrows \coprod_{i} s_i  \to X $$

where $s_i : \Delta^{n+1} \to X$ are the individual simplices.

If you really want *all* of the objects in the diagram to be copies of $\Delta^{n+1}$, you can do this in two steps:

- Each of the intersections will be of the form $\Delta^m$ for $m < n+1$. Replace this with the epimorphic image of a copy of $\Delta^{n+1}$.
- Decompose the diagram to split the coproducts into many individual objects

---

To help with all of this, recall that the nerve construction makes **Poset** a full subcategory of **sSet**, and furthermore the inclusion preserves coproducts all limits. Furthermore, $\Delta^k$ is the nerve of the poset $[k]$

All of the above can actually be carried out in **Poset** rather than **sSet**, and this fact is almost entirely due to the properties of the nerve.

The only place where we need to used the fact we are working in **sSet** is to argue that $U \to X$ is an epimorphism, and thus $X$ is computed by this coequalizer.

---

More generally, there is a systematic way to write presheaves over any small category as a colimit of representables whose source diagram is its [category of elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+elements). In the case of simplicial sets, the full subcategory spanned by the elements that are nondegenerate simplices is final, so you can restrict the source diagram to that subcategory.